# setComplexValue replace only first tag

Tags: phpword

My template docx has duplicate tags.

```php
${tag_name}
${tag_name}
${tag_name}
```

My code:

```php
$value = new TextRun();
$value->addText('tag value');
$templateProcessor->setComplexValue('tag_name', $value);
```

Result docx:

```php
tag_value //replace only first
${tag_name}
${tag_name}
```

Is this correct behavior? Is it possible to replace all tags globally?

`setValue(tag, simple_text)` works fine, but feels less elegant.

Answer (score 2):

It can go in a `while` loop like this:

```php
while ($templateProcessor->getVariableCount()[$tag]) {
    $templateProcessor->setComplexValue($tag, $value);
}
```

Comment: To avoid Undefined array key $tag you should add `$templateProcessor->getVariableCount()[$tag] ?? false`